# Array is converted to string while adding elements to it from other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm at the start of the road so bear with me. The issue is presented in the title.The code i'm using is as followed:

```
var arr = [7, 29, 8, 33, 37, 4, -31, 39, 32, -12, 9];
var even = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i]%2 == 0){
            even += arr[i];
        }
    }
console.log(even.length);
```

The code should just get the even elements from an array and move it to another.
When the code is ran, the variable "even" will hold the elements as "8432" instead of [8, 4, 32], which will give me a wrong result in console at the end: "4" instead of "3". I can't figure it out why would behave like this.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
even.push(arr[i])
```

instead of

```
even += arr[i];
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp for more example

Answer (score 1):

Use `push` rather than `+=`:

```
even.push(arr[i]);
```

In JavaScript you can kind of think of arrays as a stack (pushing and popping).

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 1):

Store your evens in a variable then push that value into the even array. Try the Snippet, it'll display the results.

### SNIPPET

```js
var arr = [7, 29, 8, 33, 37, 4, -31, 39, 32, -12, 9];
var even = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i]%2 == 0){
            var x = arr[i];
            even.push(x)
        }
    }
console.log(even);
```

```html
<!-- Results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` method

```js
var arr = [7, 29, 8, 33, 37, 4, -31, 39, 32, -12, 9];
var even = arr.filter(function(el) {
  return el % 2 == 0;
});

console.log(even);
```